# Updating a "for" attribute of a label from an array in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, label, v-for

Using VueJS, I have an array of questions to populate a form.  The questions return on the page, but all the input forms are tied together - meaning if you type in any input form, the typed text appears in all the input forms.  Can I v-bind the "for" attribute in the HTML label so that the "for" is something like "question.index" or "question.key", so that I can connect that same ID to the input?

All the input forms have the same ID and return the same information.  I cannot figure out how to dynamically add the index or key from my array to the "for" attribute in the label and then the "id" attribute in the input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vue Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div>
        <h3>Questions</h3>
        <label for="questions" ></label>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(question, index) in questions">
            {{question}}
            <input type="text" id="questions" v-model="enteredValue"/>
            <button @click="addAnswers()">Submit</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3>Answers</h3>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(answer, index) in answers">{{ answer }} </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
        questions: [
          'What is your name?', 
          'How old are you?',
          'Where do you live?'
        ],

        answers: [],
        enteredValue: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addAnswers() {
      this.answers.push(this.enteredValue);
      this.enteredValue = '';
    }
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

Comment: The problem is v-model is the same for all inputs. When the value of a v-model is updated in the script it updates in the template, and vice versa.  So when one input updates it's v-model, it updates all inputs using that same v-model.  You need something like `enteredValue` to be an array, and then bind `enteredValue[index]` to the v-model which would bind each input to a different index of the array.